# move items to a subfolder in a document library using spservices

Tags: document-library, spservices, move

Have a document library called "DocLib". it has multiple sub folders(created manually).

```
DocLib ->Folder1

DocLib ->Folder2

DocLib ->Folder3
```

and further "Folder1" has one more folder called "Archive"(created automatically through JavaScript). so basically it looks like-

```
Folder1 -> Archive1

Folder2 -> Archive2

Folder3 -> Archive3
```

**Cconsider this case**: I upload 20-25 documents inside folder1 every month. what I want is, after every 1st date of the month, those documents should move inside "Archive1" sub folder. same goes with the other folders. like documents from "folder2" should move to sub folder "Archive2" of the "folder2" so on & so forth.

Is it possible to do so? Can it be done using workflow or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Note that SharePoint was developed to abandon this old school use of Folders.

Metadata is key.

[Document Sets](http://www.threewill.com/sharepoint-document-set-primer/) (available since 2010) are a powerfull way of organizing information in *Dossiers*.

Use the [Drop Off Library](http://sharepointmadam.blogspot.nl/2015/02/drop-off-library-setup-guide.html) to route documents

'Archiving' is best (and more failsave) done with a metadata column.
Together with the [Content Organizer](http://blog.recordlion.com/sharepoint-content-organizer/) 'archived' documents can be moved to another location.

Using your own code for this; you are essentially rebuilding existing SP functionality

Comment: i learned how to use drop off library to route document to a sub folder but how can i achieve it with my conditions mentioned above ? can you provide me with an example ?  thanks.

Comment: although you are correct in all that you mention above, and folks should be using those features of Sharepoint, this response does not answer the original question. Thus why I down voted it.